# Using Google Maps on Xamarin.Forms for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

So we need to create an app that renders a map and we are currently using Xamarin.Forms to integrate it. However, we will not use Xamarin.Forms.Maps since we have to use the Google Maps API for iOS and not its native map which is MapKit.

My question is, how do I integrate this component https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices-maps in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Why don't you use Xamarin.Forms.Maps for Android and use this component for Android; https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleiosmaps or maybe use some of this 'Getting Started' code to get you going on the component you are referring to.

Comment: So it's okay if I integrate the Android map as Xamarin.Forms.Maps while I'm using the googleiosmaps for iOS?

Comment: It's not ideal in terms of code sharing etc. but it is of course an option.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'll weigh out my options. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can inject Google Map (for Android or iOS) to Xamarin.Forms's view.

Example in Android:

```
public class AndroidMapRenderer : ViewRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        var mapView = new Android.Gms.Maps.MapView(Context);
        SetNativeControl(mapView);
    }
}
```

This way is "custom renderer".

Please read these:

- [Customizing Controls on Each Platform - Xamarin](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/)
- [Customizing a Map - Xamarin](https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/map/)

Answer (score 0):

Read this guide
https://docs.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/

Control Map uses your map for each platform

Android - Google Maps

iOS - Apple Maps

Windows Phone - Bing Maps

To map must be worked for each platform to add key map, all of writing, good luck!